# Cannot connect to postgres running in Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am on a Mac.

I pulled the postgres docker image by running:

```
docker pull postgres:12.4
```

Then I start the container by running:

```
docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass -d -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

I can confirm the container is running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
6ef29362b6f3        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   pg-docker
```

I installed only `psql` on the host and when I try to connect to the postgres, I get the following error:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
password retrieved from file "/Users/me/.pgpass"
```

I am actually following the steps as outline in this [post](https://hackernoon.com/dont-install-postgres-docker-pull-postgres-bee20e200198)

I am not sure what is going wrong or how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: The Docker-level wiring looks correct; it looks like `psql` is correctly connecting to the database, but the credentials you're providing don't match.

Comment: but I am following the steps, and providing exact same credentials I used to run the container. :/